# How to Use FFT to clean the noise signal of my accelerometer

Tags: c, fft, accelerometer

I'm using a accelerometer 3-axis, to get the acceleration and then calculate the roll and pitch angles using this formula below in C.

roll = atan2(aux_y, aux_z) * 57.3;
pitch = atan2((-aux_x), sqrt(aux_y * aux_y + aux_z * aux_z)) * 57.3;

It's working fine 0º is 0.3º, but the problem is when I get some vibration noise like a motor of a truck etc, the results are "crazy" 0 goes to 22, 45,16 etc, I need to clean the vibration of my signal, some coworkers mention to me that I must to use FFT to clean it, but I'm not so sure how I gonna do that.

Comment: Perhaps a [low-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) would be enough? It should be simpler to implement and will probably be faster than using FFT.

Comment: Do you have some documentation, video or any example of how I could implement one ?  Maybe I think It mus be a HIgh-pass don't?

Comment: You want a low-pass filter, not a high-pass filter, because the desired result is the slowly changing acceleration due to the device’s change in orientation or movement and not the quickly changing acceleration due to the external vibration. Filter design is a considerable field of study with advanced mathematics. However, to start, you can try taking the average of the n most recent samples. Figure out how many samples one wavelength of the unwanted vibration spans and start with an n larger than that and see if it improves your signal. Then you can start looking into more advanced filters.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well this is extremly dependant on the filter size and bandwidth and if I recall this correctly the FFT approach gets faster quite quickly. Just because convolutions are getting expensive quite fast.

Comment: @JovemCansado Perhaps [THE SIMPLEST LOWPASS FILTER @ DspRelated](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Simplest_Lowpass_Filter_I.html) is a good place to start reading.